# How to have macros expanded by doxygen, but not documented as a define?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

Say I have:

```
#define MY_MACRO(FOO) void FOO();

MY_MACRO(hi);
MY_MACRO(hey);
MY_MACRO(hello);

#undef MY_MACRO
```

I want the macros to be expanded by doxygen, which I am able to do by configuring it the right way:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = MY_MACRO
```

This enables me to see the expanded result of the macros as documented APIs in the doxygen output (functions `hi`, `hey`, and `hello`). That is all good so far. But the problem is that, doxygen also documents `MY_MACRO` as a define. However, I do not want the clients of the API to know about `MY_MACRO`, since it is undefed and is not usable by them, and should not be visible to them.

I have `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` in my doxygen configuration and I do not want to change that. I have tried the following configuration without success:

```
PREDEFINED      = DOXYGEN_SKIP_FOR_USERS
```

With the following code:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN_SKIP_FOR_USERS
#define MY_MACRO(FOO) void FOO();
#endif /*DOXYGEN_SKIP_FOR_USERS*/

MY_MACRO(hi);
MY_MACRO(hey);
MY_MACRO(hello);

#undef MY_MACRO
```

This hides the documentation of the define, but of course prevents the expansion, so I do not get the functions documented in the generated API.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supposing that `MY_` is the prefix that you are using consistently in your code :) I would use the prefix `MY__` (two underscores) for internal macros and then put something like

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = MY__*
```

in the `Doxygen` configuration file.

**Edit:** the double underscore inside symbols is reserved for C++ (not for C). So if you want to be compatible with C and C++ you should choose some other type of convention. Unfortunately a leading underscore is reserved, too, so `_MY_` wouldn't do neither.

Comment: A note on the double underscore: Names containing a double underscore are reserved for use by the compiler. To avoid stepping on each others toes, it is best to avoid using a double underscore in your own identifiers.

Comment: @Bart Do you have a citation handy?  I thought it was only identifiers starting with a double underscore.  (And global identifiers starting with an underscore at all, etc.)

Comment: @Bart and @llasram: I think that this double underscore rule is a C++ rule, not for C. (I didn't notice the C++ flag). But in any case for the purpose we are talking about here, one can easily figure out just some other, not too nasty, prefix.

Comment: I don't see EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS in doxygen documentation at: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/config.html

Comment: @bugur: yes strange, that it is not documented there. But it appears and is documented in the default configuration file that doxygen produces.

Comment: I created a bugzilla item on documentation.

Comment: @Jens and @llasram: The double underscore is indeed C++ only and is stated in clause 17.4.3.1.2 of the C++ standard. For me, the issue was worth commenting on, but not worth a downvote.

Comment: @Bart: I never thought you would. For the double underscore, thanks for digging this out. It sounds reasonable for C++, it has to leave naming conventions for function name mangling. I will edit my answer, so people don't have to did through the comments.